# Difference between default and hosted agent queue?

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, azure-devops

When I create a build definition I'm asked for one or the other. What is the main difference? Is this a dummy question? I'm new on configuring build templates. I can create them, but I want to understand them also!

Answer (score 10):

The [Hosted queue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/vs/alm/Build/services/hosted-agent-pool) is Microsoft's queue. It has a certain set of capabilities available, and you can't change that.

The "Default" queue is your on-premise build agents, assuming you set them up. You can create multiple queues, as well.